# How to fetch media data for each loop item

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Basically I got two fetching paths, I want to display each media (jpg,audio) etc. for each `clue`. Do I need to fetch it by id in the html, are there better ways to do it?

```
chapters/:chapter_id/clues   
chapters/:chapter_id/clues/:clue_id/media
```

Do I need something like?

```html
<div v-for="clue in clues" :key="clue.id">
[{clue.name}}
Media: {{ fetchMediaClue(route.params.id, clue.id) }}
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 possibilities!

1. once (I guess in the mounted) loaded with data of the **clues**, load in another prop the data of the media

```js
this.mediaClues = await Promise.all(
      this.clues.map((clue) => fetchMediaClue(this.route.params.id, clue.id))
    );
```

2. make a component that autonomously loads data from the API

```html
<div v-for="clue in clues" :key="clue.id">
[{clue.name}}
<media-component :clue-id="clue.id" :other-prop="route.params.id" /> 
</div>
```